# Magento Empty cart using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, cart

I am currently trying to empty the whole cart in mangento 1.9 while clicking an item.
The code is in the list.phtml from my template.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="POST" name="emptyTheCart">
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
            <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" style="display:none" title="<?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?>" id="empty_cart_button"></button>
      </form>
```

---

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    var dataExecURL = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>";
         var datafiles=$("#emptyTheCart").serialize();
          $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : datafiles,
                url  : dataExecURL



            });
});
```

when i click on an item, it should empty my cart. Can someone please help?
I do not have any clues why this is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make several modifications on the request, and now I have succeded.

```
$('.item').click(function() {
$(this).find('input:radio')[0].checked = true;
```

var formurl = $(this).find('input:radio').val();

```
        var datafile=$("#product_addtocart_form").serialize();
    var dataExecURL = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>";
     var datafiles=$("#emptyTheCart").serialize();
     datafiles = datafiles + "&update_cart_action=empty_cart";

     $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : datafiles,
            url  : dataExecURL,
            success: function()
            {
                  $.ajax({
                            type : 'POST',
                            data : datafile,
                            url  : formurl



                        });
            }


        });

        // console.log(datafile);
```

});

also I have added the form mentioned earlier at the bottom of the document.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `id="#emptyTheCart"` to the form, since you are using `$("#emptyTheCart").serialize()` but the form doesn't seem to have any id?

Other than that, your code looks correct.

Comment: i have just added the id to the form and the cart is still not being emptied

Comment: I have just tried again but this time i have added
 datafiles = datafiles + "&update_cart_action=empty_cart";

and the cart was emptied